# HTML server control vs. HTML elements

Tags: asp.net

Newbie question:
There are three types of Asp.Net controls : HTML server controls, Web controls and User controls. Out of these I understand the utility of web controls and user controls. But what is the use of HTML server controls? 
Under what circumstances would I need to use HTML server controls? Whatever I want to do I can do using either simple HTML elements OR the Web controls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, having HTML server controls make it possible to write code which differentiates between tags logic and tags themselves.

See [here](http://www.asp101.com/lessons/htmlcontrols.asp) for an example.